# Spring-WS, REST, SOAP, HTTP, JMS

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

I've just started out on my web service journey and now I have a lot of questions. There's a lot of things that aren't clear to me so some clarification would be really helpful.

1. Why isn't the `@Endpoint` annotation used when creating a Spring 3
   REST application?
2. Does a Spring REST web service also create a .wsdl?
3. What is the difference between SOAP and REST?
4. How do you send a request and receive a response with a SOAP web
   service?
5. How do you send a request and receive a response with a REST web
   service?
6. Is it possible to use JMS with Spring to expose either a REST or
   SOAP web service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too many questions in one... question, but here's some overview:

> Why isn't the `@Endpoint` annotation used when creating a Spring 3 REST application?

For REST you can either use external JAX-RS framework or Spring MVC. REST endpoints in Spring are basically controllers, and this is how they are annotated. `@Endpoint` is introduced in `spring-ws` module, they are not really related.

> Does a Spring REST web service also create a .wsdl?

No, traditionally WSDL was used only to describe SOAP web services. REST web services have [wadl](/questions/tagged/wadl), Spring is not ([yet](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8705)) generating it automatically.

> What is the difference between SOAP and REST?

Very broad question. In principle SOAP uses well-defined XML messages, typically over HTTP POST. REST is inherently connected to HTTP verbs like GET, POST, PUT, content negotation, HATEOS... It is much closer related to HTTP protocol and much more flexible.

> How do you send a request and receive a response with a SOAP web service?

Any client capable of sending XML over HTTP POST can interact with SOAP services. Typically you'll create Java-client based on WSDL (not that simple with REST).

> How do you send a request and receive a response with a REST web service?

The same way as above, but typically you can use different content types, like JSON. Also you must use different HTTP methods to run different functionality.

> Is it possible to use JMS with Spring to expose either a REST or SOAP web service?

Not sure what you want to achieve... Technically you can use JMS as a transport layer for SOAP (not for REST), but this is way too advanced for the beginning.